# camel xpath: TransformerException: Unable to evaluate expression using this context

Tags: xml, xpath, apache-camel

I'm trying to use camel xpath filter in my camel route. I get an error in my unit test that I cannot solve. I Would appreciate some help.

When trying to analyse the following xml:

```
<publication>

<publicationId>1</publicationId>
<alias>false</alias>
<publicationType>NEW</publicationType>
<zone>VALIDATION</zone>
<routingKey>WWX_VECTOR</routingKey>
<contexts>
    <context>GEO</context>
</contexts>

<resource>
    <resourceFamily>
        <releasedOnPww>false</releasedOnPww>
    </resourceFamily>
    <featureType>
        <name>buildings</name>
    </featureType>
</resource>
</publication>
```

With the following xpath:

```
.filter().xpath("/publication/resource/resourceFamily/releasedOnPww/text() = 'true'")
```

I get the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to evaluate expression using this context
at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.axes.NodeSequence.setRoot(NodeSequence.java:212)
at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.axes.LocPathIterator.execute(LocPathIterator.java:210)
at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.Expression.execute(Expression.java:153)
at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.operations.Operation.execute(Operation.java:107)
at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.XPath.execute(XPath.java:335)
```

What's kind of weird is that the code seems to run OK in run-time, the error occurs only during unit testing.

Comment: Can you share parts from your route and unit test?

Comment: Would be difficult to share the code Itsallas because it's quite big... Anyway I think that the message might be empty before rushing my xpath. If the event is null, could that explain the matter?

Comment: There is nothing wrong in your xpath expression. I got the same exception in a unit test with null body in the exchange. When the exchange body is not null it works as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should try this

```
.filter().xpath("/publication/resource/resourceFamily[releasedOnPww='true']")
```

May be the problem in namespace see this thread http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/fail-filter-XPATH-camel-td476424.html

**EDIT:** My comment able to solve the problem, as @Mylen said. So i am including the comment into this answer.
Even your Xpath Expression looks fine. Once try to check XML in body `.log(" (body) = ${body}")`. May be consumed XML is not same as expected one.

Comment: I've tried that solution without success yesterday... Same error shows up.

Comment: I'm not using any NS, so it does not relate to your link. Thanks for your help anyway

Comment: Even your Xpath Expression looks fine. Once try to check XML in body `.log(" (body) = ${body}")`. May be consumed XML is not same as expected one.